# dc.js is not loading in jsp but it does in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I am using `dc.js` in HTML and JSP pages. In HTML, the js library is loading but for JSP, it does not able to load.

And its throwing a reference error, dc is not defined. I have checked in debugging  mode, the `dc.js` is not listed in the source but it does for html page. Any help would be highly appreciated.

**code clip for the jsp:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../javascripts/d3.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../javascripts/crossfilter.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../javascripts/dc.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
```

Comment: Can you post your project structure ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be due to the directory listings problems (path). Try to provide the abosulte path . For example,

If you placed the `js` files inside the `webcontent -> javascripts`, then access it like ,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= request.getContextPath() %>/javascripts/dc.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/javascripts/dc.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
```

to get rid of path problems.Similarly for other includes.

**Upadate from the comments :**

It was caused due to multiple includes of `d3.js` in the same file 
Hope this helps!!

Comment: thanks for the comments. I have checked with above code, but the problem still persist. It could able to load the other libraries like d3,js, crossfilter.js. Is there would be any other reason for this issues.

Comment: thanks @San. It was due to multiple definition of d3.js. now working fine :)

Comment: You are welcome :) will edit my answer though . Mark it as accepted if it helped you :)